# gspread: how to change the color of an entire row?

Tags: gspread

I have the following DataFrame:

```
actor          Daily Total   actor1  actor2
Day
2019-01-01     25            10       15
2019-01-02     30            15       15
Avg            27.5          12.5     15.0
```

While writing to a worksheet of spreadsheet, how do I change the color of entire 'Avg' row? How can I highlight it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the same question and found an answer (from the year 2019). We can use [gspread-formatting](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting/).

```
pip install gspread-formatting
from gspread_formatting  import *
```

Suppose we've already had a worksheet, wks, from a spreadsheet

```
fmt = cellFormat(
backgroundColor=color(1, 1, 0), #set it to yellow
textFormat=textFormat(foregroundColor=color(1, 0, 0)),
)
#red: (1,0,0), white: (1,1,1)
row = 3
format_cell_range(wks, rowcol_to_a1(row,1)+':' + rowcol_to_a1(row, wks.col_count), fmt)
```

If we want to highlight the text, modify the code in cellFormat

```
fmt = cellFormat(
backgroundColor=color(1, 1, 0), #set it to yellow
textFormat=textFormat(foregroundColor=color(1, 0, 0)),
)
```

Comment: hello how did you figure out the color code? I tried to follow the RGB format but it did not worked on the spreadsheet it shows up a different color :(

Comment: Could you provide your code? According to [gspread_formatting's document](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/), we need to use color code from google sheet api definition (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color) that is RGB, each has range in [0,1]